# mysql: why comparing a 'string' to 0 gives true?

Tags: mysql, string, comparison

I was doing some MySQL test queries, and realized that comparing a string column with `0` (as a number) gives `TRUE`!

```
select 'string' = 0 as res; -- res = 1 (true), UNexpected! why!??!?!
```

however, comparing it to any other number, positive or negative, integer or decimal, gives `false` as expected
(of course unless the string is the representation of the number as string)

```
select 'string' = -12 as res; -- res = 0 (false), expected
select 'string' = 3131.7 as res; -- res = 0 (false), expected
select '-12' = -12 as res; -- res = 1 (true), expected
```

Of course comparing the string with `'0'` as string, gives false, as expected.

```
select 'string' = '0' as res; -- res = 0 (false), expected
```

but why does it give true for `'string' = 0` ?

why is that?

Comment: MySQL has to convert string to a number or number to a string. If it converts 'string' to number, it may be coming back with `0`. So `0 = 0`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

MySQL automatically casts a string to a number:

```
SELECT '1string' = 0 AS res; -- res = 0 (false)
SELECT '1string' = 1 AS res; -- res = 1 (true)
SELECT '0string' = 0 AS res; -- res = 1 (true)
```

and a string that does not begin with a number is evaluated as 0:

```
SELECT 'string' = 0 AS res;  -- res = 1 (true)
```

Of course, when we try to compare a string with another string there's no conversion:

```
SELECT '0string' = 'string' AS res; -- res = 0 (false)
```

but we can force a conversion using, for example, a + operator:

```
SELECT '0string' + 0 = 'string' AS res; -- res = 1 (true)
```

last query returns TRUE because we ar summing a string '0string' with a number 0, so the string has to be converted to a number, it becomes `SELECT 0 + 0 = 'string'` and then again the string 'string' is converted to a number before being compared to 0, and it then becomes `SELECT 0 = 0` which is TRUE.

This will also work:

```
SELECT '1abc' + '2ef' AS total; -- total = 1+2 = 3
```

and will return the sum of the strings converted to numbers (1 + 2 in this case).

Comment: would you mind elaborating the last example? It is unclear why it gives true.

Comment: @DiegoDD please see my updated answer, let me know if there's anything unclear

Answer (score 2):

["Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal) This means that in order to compare a string to a number, it tries to parse a number from the start of the string. In this case there is no number there, so it converts to 0, and 0 = 0 is true.

Comment: I see! I believed it would try to do it the other way, parse the 0 to a string and then compare it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix it you can compare two strings:

```
select 'string' = convert(0,char) as res --- res = 0
```