# Mysqli Update Prepare Failing

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE profile SET fullname =?, guardian =?,   
 addressline1 = ?, addressline2 = ?, city = ?, stateid = ?, pin = ?, birthdate = ?, 
 bloodgroup= ?, allergydetails= ?, pancardno= ?, officephone= ?, residencephone= ?, 
 mobilephone= ?, drivinglicensenumber= ?, drivinglicensevalidupto= ?, 
 fmscidrivinglicensenumber= ?, fmscientrantlicensenumber= ?, vehiclemake= ?, 
 vehiclemodel= ?, vehiclenumber= ?, vehicleyear= ?, emergencyname= ?, 
 emergencyaddress1= ?, emergencyaddress2= ?,emergencylandphone= ?,  
 emergencymobilephone= ?, isprofilecomplete = ?  WHERE username = ?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param('sssssississsssssssssssssssssi', $fullname, $sodowo, 
addressline1,     $addressline2, $city, $stateid, $pin, $birthdate, $bloodgroup, 
$allergydetails, $pancardno, $officephone, $residencephone, $mobilephone,  
$drivinglicensenumber, $drivinglicensevalidupto, $fmscidrivinglicensenumber,    
$fmscientrantlicensenumber, $vehiclemake, $vehiclemodel, $vehiclenumber, $vehicleyear, 
$emergencyname, $emergencyaddress1, $emergencyaddress2, $emergencylandphone, 
 $emergencymobilephone, $isprofilecomplete , $username );
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();

 }
```

When the above update statement is executed it is updating all the rows with the values instead of the WHERE clause. Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the value of `$username`?

Comment: WHERE username = $username

Comment: No what's the value of the variable `$username`? I.e. whats the output of `echo $username;`?

Comment: You use `i` for last param (username) in `bind_param`. Looks like it is not correct. Try to replace with `s`.

Comment: That would be the session value of the logged in user.

Comment: Phantom looks like you found the error. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last value of the types string for bind param (first parameter ("sssssississsssssssssssssssssi") is an "i" for integer but you're comparing it to "username" which is probably a string.

I guess the value you're passing in is converted to 0 and comparing 0 to any string in MySQL is always true (see [mysql: why comparing a 'string' to 0 gives true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080382/mysql-why-comparing-a-string-to-0-gives-true)).

Try changing the last "i" for a "s" in "sssssississsssssssssssssssssi" (which is really horrible to read and hence very error-prone btw.)

Comment: Yes it has been sorted out. Is there a better way to write bind params?

Comment: I would rather switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php) and use [bindValue](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) which takes the type as third parameter.