# Database query returning incorrect row

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm working on some web code which uses codeigniter and the built in querybuilder to access a database.

I attempt to load data from the database for the current user

```
$userModel = $this->loadModel('ModelUser');
$name = $this->session->userdata('user');
$user = $userModel->getUser($name);
```

This is the code for`getUser`:

```
function getUser($username)
{
    $this->db->where('username',$username);
    $query = $this->db->get('tblusers',1);
    $res = $query->result();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        log_message('debug','Got user. ID = '.$res[0]->id);
        foreach($res[0] as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->$key = $val;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    else {
        log_message('info','failed to find user '.$username);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

This works fine except when I let the session expire, in which case I get the details of another user.

These are the results of testing `getUser`:

```
$userModel->getUser("Admin"); //Got user. ID = Admin_ID
$userModel->getUser("john");  //Got user. ID = John_ID
$userModel->getUser("");      //Failed to find user
$userModel->getUser(null);    //Failed to find user
```

When I log in as `Admin` then let the session timeout, the top snippet logs the message:

`Got user. ID = John_ID`

I would expect either `Got user. ID = Admin_ID` or `Failed to find user`

Comment: you can call this function when session is set other wise don't call this function you can set message **session is expired**.

Comment: I understand how to prevent the issue, but I don't understand the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$this->session->userdata('field')` does not find an entry, it returns `0` instead of the `""` or `null` that I was testing against.

Logging `$this->db->last_query()` showed this since the resulting query was:

```
SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE username = 0 LIMIT 1;
```

MySQL will automatically convert strings to integers where the string starts with an integer. A string without an integer will be cast to `0` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22080540/3392335). The query was returning the first entry it came across instead of finding no rows as any string that didn't start with 1-9 would match the WHERE clause.

I added a clause to `getUser` to return `NULL` if `$username == ''`. I did try `=== 0` but that yielded the same error so there's some type coercion going on that I'm not 100% certain of, but this covers the issue nicer than handling the case each time `getUser` is called.