# Why does ""=" exploit this MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, security

On a MySQL 5.6 database, I build this simple table and insert a row:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` ( 
`username` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, 
`password` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES ('bob', 'pass');
```

Then I set up a query in PHP like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * from users where username=\"".$username."\" and password=\"".$password."\"";
```

When `$username` and `$password` are both equal to `""="`, the resulting query is `SELECT * from users where username="""="" and password="""=""`. When that's used to query the table set up before, the row in the table is returned.

The question is, how is MySQL evaluating that query such that it considers the query valid and that the WHERE statement is true? Assuming all double-quotes are matched with the nearest untaken adjacent double-quote, I would have expected the query to be interpreted something like this, which looks like it should be considered gibberish:

```
SELECT * from users where username=""
"="
" and password="
""
=
""
```

Here's an example of this behavior on a MySQL 5.6 DB: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02e606/2

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/ use parameter instead.

Comment: This is a deliberate vulnerability in a simple "into to SQL injection" challenge I solved. The question is why this particular solution worked rather than how to secure it. But I do enjoy that strip.

Comment: run an `EXPLAIN` on the query and see how _MySQL_ is evaluating it...

Comment: Aside from the SQLi problem, please *never* store passwords as plain text. They should be *properly* salted and hashed using a secure library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because MySQL allows `""` as an alternative for `\"`.

```
mysql> select '"foo"' = """foo""", '"foo"' = "\"foo\"", 'foo' = """foo""";
+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| '"foo"' = """foo""" | '"foo"' = "\"foo\"" | 'foo' = """foo""" |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|                   1 |                   1 |                 0 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In your specific case:

```
SELECT * from users where username="""="" and password="""=""
```

would be the same as (if I'm parsing this correctly in my head):

```
SELECT * from users where (username='"="" and passsword="') = ""
```

A three-way equality test IS syntactically correct, but does not evaluate as expected

```
mysql> select 'a' = 'a' = 'a';
+-----------------+
| 'a' = 'a' = 'a' |
+-----------------+
|               0 |
+-----------------+
```

because that parses as `(a=a)=a` -> `true=a` -> `false`

-- 
comment follow up for @juan:

```
mysql> select 'a'='a'='a', 'a'='a'='b', 'a'='b'='a', 'b'='a'='a', 'b'='b'='a';
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 'a'='a'='a' | 'a'='a'='b' | 'a'='b'='a' | 'b'='a'='a' | 'b'='b'='a' |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|           0 |           0 |           1 |           1 |           0 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

It's non-intuitive, because

```
mysql> select 'a'=('a'='b'), ('a'='a')='b', true='b', 'a'=false;
+---------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| 'a'=('a'='b') | ('a'='a')='b' | true='b' | 'a'=false |
+---------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|             1 |             0 |        0 |         1 |
+---------------+---------------+----------+-----------+
```

--- followup to the followup: again, your original query:

```
SELECT * from users where username="""="" and password="""=""
```

will run as

```
SELECT * from users where (username='"="" and passsword="') = ""
SELECT * from users where (false) = ""
SELECT * from users where true
```

because `false =""` in mysql evaluates to TRUE, therefore ALL rows get included, unless you have a user whose username is literally `"="" and password="`.

Comment: [Relevant manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html). I personally didn't know mysql supported this but have been working with Oracle db for a while now and that is how they escape quotes.

Comment: if `a' = 'a' = 'a'` evaluate to `0` how `WHERE 0` return the row?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: because it's not a table filter. it's selecting a literal value, which happens to be an all-constants expression. it's no different than `select 1` or `select false`.

Comment: @MarcB So it would read it as

    `SELECT * from users where username=\""=\" and password=\""=\"`

I'm still not seeing how that's valid SQL, though. That leaves two unescaped double-quotes, so we're looking at something like:

    `SELECT * from users where username= \" 
    "=\" and password=\""
    =\"`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: because in all cases, a `where` clauses boils down a boolean true/false. false = this row is NOT included in the result, true = include the row. Doesn't matter how true/false the value you're selecting is, if you have `where 0`, you automatically exclude ALL rows. exactly the same as `where 1` or `where true` or `where 'hi mom'` would INCLUDE all rows.

Comment: still dont understand why these two cases give different result? `'a' = 'a' = 'a'` vs `'a' = b' = 'a'`   `false/true <> 'a'` http://rextester.com/IJAKG55845

Comment: Your three way equality works like this, `username`=`""="" and password="` = `""`. So you are comparing the username to a string that doesn't match (false) and then comparing false to an empty string which would cast to false on comparison. So it ends up being `false=false`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Check my example, looks like `false = 'a'` -> `true`

Comment: The `a=a=a` one would return no rows. I'm just saying that the original code is more like `b=a=false` where `b=a` evaluates to false and then is compared to a false value which is true.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I agree `b=a` evaluate to `false` but how `false = 'a'` evaluate to `true`?

Comment: It doesn't. But the original query ends with `=""` meaning that it is comparing `false` (from `username="something not username"`) and that is compared to `""` or an empty string. Which would be converted to a boolean false.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Again check the fiddle demo, even if end with `= 'a'` also return `true`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I was backwards a little. Mysql doesn't have real booleans, they typically use 0 and 1 respectively. The result of the username comparison returns 0 and mysql, when comparing number/string converts the string to number. Strings not starting with a number casts to 0 while any string starting with a number casts to the number up to the first non digit. So `"123test"=123` is true while `a=a=a` results in `a=a` is true (1) compared to `a` which casts to `0` and ends up being `1=0`. [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080382/mysql-why-comparing-a-string-to-0-gives-true)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are doing something like this

**[Sql Demo](http://rextester.com/XRMP75278)**

```
SELECT """="" and password="""=""   -- this is equal to 0
from users 
where (username = "anything") = false;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In MYSQL you can escape single and double quotes like this:

Instead of `\"` you can do this `""` when useing `"` as field wrapper.
Same with `\'` becomes `''` when using `'` as field wrapper

And what in MYSQL also work is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = 'ab' 'b c'
```

real query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name = 'abb c'
```

See Online MYSQL Documention