# How does MySql cast a string to a DECIMAL?

Tags: mysql

In MySql, result of `select CAST('sdgdg32aannx' as DECIMAL)` is `0`, and result of `select CAST('32aannx' as DECIMAL)` is `32`.

How does MySql cast a string to decimal? Where is the document about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080382/mysql-why-comparing-a-string-to-0-gives-true -- I am searching for the actual MySQL docs which describe the behavior. It's something I have long understood and taken for granted but I hope to find the documentation. It isn't mentioned in the `CAST()` docs

Comment: The rule though is that if a CHAR value begins with numerals like `32aannx`, it will be cast as int/dec up to the first non-numeric char - `32`. If it does not begin with numerals, strings will always cast to `0`

Comment: [Type conversion for comparison operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) includes a list _illustrate conversion of strings to numbers for comparison operations:_ that demonstrates the operations if not actually spelling out the rule