# SQL – What's the difference between this two codes?

Tags: mysql, or-condition

```
select sex, id from qualification where cid = ('Male' or 'Female')
```

vs

```
select sex, id from qualification where cid = 'Male' or cid = 'Female'
```

The first code would generate all of the items while the second gives what I want.

In a sense, we can't have or in a brackets for sql?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! wouldn't `('Male' or 'Female')` will resolve to `false`?

Comment: In a sense, we can't have or in a brackets for sql? - CORRECT the shorthand equivalent of your second query is cid IN('Male' , 'Female')

Comment: See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b35938 ('Male' or 'Female') is evaluated to 0

Answer (score 2):

MySQL normally [`cast`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) a value to another type for our convenience. One example of it would be casting a string into number.

MySQL can cast a string into a number by relying on the leading number of the said string. For example:

```
select cast('test' as signed); //returns 0
select cast('1test' as signed); //returns 1
```

This has been discussed before on another [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080382/mysql-why-comparing-a-string-to-0-gives-true) as Gelu pointed out.

On another note, `true` represented as `1` and `false` represented as `0` in bit.

---

Now let's examine your query:

```
select sex, id from qualification where cid = ('Male' or 'Female')
```

Lets resolve bit-by-bit on the `where` clause.

```
cid = ('Male' or 'Female')
```

The `or` operator accepts two `boolean` operand. On your case that would be `'Male'` and `'Female'`. Based on how MySQL handles casting, both `'Male'` and `'Female'` would return as 0 given they have no leading number at all.

```
cid = (0 or 0)
```

An `or` with both operand valued as `false` will result `false`. After resolving the `('Male' or 'Female')` the `where` clause will be:

```
cid = 0
```

With the assumption that `cid` column contains string without any leading number at all, we can assert that all `cid` casted as `0`. It will result your query to be rewritten as:

```
select sex, id from qualification where 0 = 0
```

Which also meant:

```
select sex, id from qualification where true
```

The query above will return all rows.

**Edit**:
Major restructuring on the answer. I feel the previous answer might be a bit confusing.

Comment: Related to the cast of the string to 0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080382/mysql-why-comparing-a-string-to-0-gives-true